# How can I fix C# comment headers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

After using an automatic comment header application, I found that it deleted the last return before the code started. This means that all of my files in the solution now look like this:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  File Name: Mapper.cs
//  Creation Date: 13/02/2013
//  Author: person
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
```

I have a couple of hundred of files I now need to fix and my source control went away (Was on an EC2 Micro that lapsed). I seem to have encountered a series of unfortunate events here. Is there a macro, or something similar, that can help me get out of this bind?

Comment: Does Find/Replace work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio you can do a replace all with wild cards enabling you to insert the line break. I don't have the IDE available now but it should be something like this:

Search in all files in the project for this using wildcards:

```
---using
```

Replace this by:

```
---\nusing
```

Or as Kirk suggested, use regex.

Search for:

```
---.*
```

Replace by:

```
---\n\1
```

Comment: (with "regular expressions" -- `.*`)

Comment: @Kirk: that's an option too, but scares a lot users not familiar with regex.

Comment: I don't think I've seen "wildcards" as an option for a while.  (not in VS2012 or VS2013 that I can see)

Comment: @Kirk: this should work now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Regex was the answer. When I am in Visual Studio I don't think of Regex right away, but very useful tip! I had to fix the usings and a few namespace declarations as well. Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A different approach from using the IDE, you could start your [LinqPAD](http://www.linqpad.net/) and then run this code 
(well a backup before is not to forget)

```
void Main()
{
    string yourRootSolutionPath = @"D:\temp";
    foreach(string s in Directory.EnumerateFiles(yourRootSolutionPath, "*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(s);
        for(int x = 0; x < lines.Length; x++)
        {
            int pos = lines[x].IndexOf("---using");
            if(pos > 0)
            {
                lines[x] = lines[x].Substring(0, pos+3) + Environment.NewLine + lines[x].Substring(pos+3);
                File.WriteAllLines(s, lines);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on `Edit > Find and Replace > Find in Files`.
2. In the find and replace dialog box, expand the `Find options` group box and enable
   `Use Regular Expressions`.
3. In the `Find what:` drop down paste `-using System;`
4. In the `Replace with:` drop down paste `-\rusing System;`
5. In the `Look in:` drop down use `Entire Solution`.
6. Optional: You can restrict your search further by adding a `*.cs` to the `Look at these file types:` drop down.

Try your search with the `Find Next` and `Replace` options. If things look good, then **pray to the Visual Studio Gods** and click the `Replace All` button.